# How do i perform an arabic search in SQL Lite ignoring diacritics?

Tags: ios, iphone, sql, database, sqlite

I'm trying to extract words that are stored in my SQL Lite database with ignoring diacritics but it always return an empty result. my database contains arabic words with diacritics and i would to make a search with words which are don't contain diacritics.

```
    NSString *queryStatement = [[NSString alloc ]initWithFormat:@"SELECT ID,ARABIC, ARABICMEANING, FRENCHINARABIC, FRENCH, BEGINARABIC,BEGINFRENCH,ISFAVORITE  FROM DictionaryDB WHERE FRENCHINARABIC LIKE \"%%%@%%\"",searchedWord];
```

For example searchedWord can be @"أكل" and can be with diacritics @"أَكَلَ".

How can i resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved such a thing by creating my own SQLite function that does this.

The basic idea is your query becomes:

```
NSString *queryStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"SELECT ID, ARABIC, ARABICMEANING, FRENCHINARABIC, FRENCH, BEGINARABIC, BEGINFRENCH, ISFAVORITE FROM DictionaryDB WHERE contains(FRENCHINARABIC, '%@')", searchedWord];
```

where `contains` will be your custom function.

First you need to write a C function that implements the `contains` SQL function:

```
void contains(sqlite3_context *context, int argc, sqlite3_value **argv) {
    BOOL res = NO;
    if (argc < 2) {
        res = NO;
    } else {
        char *textstr = (char *)sqlite3_value_text(argv[0]);
        char *substr = (char *)sqlite3_value_text(argv[1]);
        if (textstr && substr) {
            NSString *text = [NSString stringWithCString:textstr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            NSString *sub = [NSString stringWithCString:substr encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

            // Adjust the options to suit your needs
            NSRange range = [text rangeOfString:sub options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch | NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch | NSWidthInsensitiveSearch];
            if (range.location != NSNotFound) {
                res = YES;
            }
        }
    }

    sqlite3_result_int(context, res ? 1 : 0);
}
```

When you open your database connection you need to register this function:

```
// dbRef is your database reference
int res = sqlite3_create_function(dbRef, "contains", 2, SQLITE_UTF8, NULL, &contains, NULL, NULL);
if (res != SQLITE_OK) {
    NSAssert1(0, @"Error: failed to create function in the database: '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(dbRef));
}
```

Side note - it's a bad idea to use `stringWithFormat:` to create your query. You should really consider using the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions to properly bind a value to a query. Using `stringWithFormat:` will fail if the value has any quotes or other special values. Using the `sqlite3_bind_xxx` functions takes care of properly quoting and escaping values.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by replacing the diacritics 
here my correct query 

 `@"SELECT ID,ARABIC, ARABICMEANING, FRENCHINARABIC, FRENCH, BEGINARABIC,BEGINFRENCH,ISFAVORITE  FROM DictionaryDB WHERE 
 replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace (replace(ARABICMEANING, 'ِ', ''),'ٍ',''),'ْ',''),'ّ','' ),'ٌ',''),'ُ',''),'ً',''),'َ','')LIKE \"%%%@%%\"",@"أكل"];`

Comment: THat's pretty ugly and not very scalable. You should consider my solution.